# Xpath expression - Dom failed

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, dom

I'm trying to find a div in a dom `<div class="pointsAvailable">4</div>`.
My goal is to retrieve the 4 value.

Impossible to do with this following code :

```
heros_countpoint_path = "//div[@id='background']/div[@id='center']/div[@id='contentOuterContainer']/div[@class='contentContainer']/div[@id='content']/div[@id='heroV2']/div[contains(@class,'pointsAvailable')]"
data_heros_countpoint = driver.find_element(By. XPATH, heros_countpoint_path)
retrieve_heros_countpoint = data_heros_countpoint.text
print(retrieve_heros_countpoint)
```

DOM :

[DOM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UuqXK.jpg)

I'm trying to use CSS_SELECTOR method, XPATH expression, CLASS_NAME or TAG_NAME locators.
I'm expecting to retrieve the 4 value.

I think the div with the same class AttributeBox is a part of the error I have.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a xpath with both class and text i.e.

```
//*[contains(@class, 'pointsAvailable')]//*[text() = '4']
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Does not work for me